# For Legendre's Equation $P_n(x)$: $(1-x^2)P_n^{''}(x) - 2xP_n^{'}(x) + n(n+1)P_n^{}(x) = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

**Claim**

Let $P_n: \Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb R $, $n \in \Bbb N\cup\{0\}$

$P_n(x):={1\over{2^n{n!}}}{d^n\over dx^n}[(x^2-1)^n]$, then $P_n$ has n distinct roots in ]-1, 1[

Then show that below equation is fulfilled.

$(1-x^2)P_n^{''}(x) - 2xP_n^{'}(x) + n(n+1)P_n^{}(x) = 0$

**Question**

I had tried brute way, but it doesn't conclude to 0. and also induction doesn't work to me too.

Any other way to show this?

Comment: Check the postings in "Related", you will see that some of them contain the answers you are looking for.

Comment: See my post on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580886/proof-legendre-polynomials-solving-the-corresponding-differential-equation/765533#765533